# Xamarin Android DownloadString takes ages or not even works

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin, mono

i started using Xamarin for Android yesterday and yeah well its pretty nice. 
But of course there must be some mistakes i do like everyone.

What i try is simply downloading the HTML of www.google.com asynchronously with this lines of code:

```
    private async void btnAuthenticate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "method is being called", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        string test = await Task.Run(() => new WebClient().DownloadString("http://google.de/"));
        Toast.MakeText(this, test, ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
```

When clicking the button, the Toast "method is being called" appears and mostly nothing else. At first it takes at least 1 1/2 minutes to show some reaction, either the app crashs, does nothing or it prints out what i want. Lets say on 10 tries it prints out 2 times the expected.

I tried the same code with an WPF C# Desktop Application and it works fine.

The application not even freezes or something. 
The debugger outputs mostly the same:

"Worker starting"
or sometimes it says "hill climbing, change max number of threads x"
or
"Thread started:  #X"
i dont know if this is relevant.

Also, i am using Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin for Android (30-Day Trial for now).

Edit: I modified the app to start downloading the webpage as soon as the app starts with the same behaviour. I then created a logcat log from this which you can see [here](http://pastebin.com/p8Ra8kpY).

Edit²: I also created a new project using Xamarin Studio this time. I modified the following:

1. Added Internet permission to manifest.
2. Changed the default button code to my needs.

Here is the source of this app, could someone try this on his own and tell me if it also takes more than 30 seconds to make this webrequest which should be actually completed within 1-2 seconds. [Here is the demo project](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11179015/test.zip.html).

I hope you guys can help me out there.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the asynchronous nature of your code; `Toast` is only designed to display **short** messages.

For me, that web request to `http://google.de/` contains about 48k characters. Giving `Toast` that much content will cause it to lock up the UI thread while it builds the view to render to the screen.

You can verify that the code is indeed asynchronous by wrapping a progress dialog around the web request:

```
var pd = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Downloading...", "Fetching content from \"http://google.de/\""); 
string content = await Task.Run(() => new WebClient().DownloadString("http://google.de/"));
pd.Dismiss();
```

You'll notice that the `ProgressDialog` will appear and spin (which means the web-request is in a background thread as the UI is not locked up) and it'll dismiss when the web request task finishes.

Comment: Well, i should have probably said, that i already properly debugged my application and its definately the asynchronous code that takes ages to complete. Now i tested it just again with your code. The ProgressDialog was loading at least 1 minute. Right after that Visual Studio opened a small windows saying that an unhandled exception occured without more information.

Comment: In that case include the logcat output in your question as that'll give clues on why the error is causing.

Comment: Make sure you have included the `android.permission.INTERNET` in your manifest as well.

Comment: Yep, it is, sometimes it works like i said but only after 1 minute. But mostly it´s just throwing unhandled exception.

Comment: I tried this example out: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/web_services/consuming_services/call_a_rest_web_service/

I put exact the same code into my application and its everything working fine. But as soon as i change the URL to another it takes 1 minute and after this minute it shows the correct result.